# Enumerate SD cards mounted on Android phone

Tags: android, sd-card, mount

How can I from either Java or native code enumerate all SD cards mounted on Android phone?

Comment: You can't precisely, however you can read /proc/mounts and filter things that have characteristics suggesting they might be sdcards or comparable soldered-in storage volumes.

Answer (score 0):

This would not only list the mounted sdcards but also all the mounted filesystems on an Android device.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("cat /proc/mounts");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
// read the output from the command
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to run the mount command as a distinct executable (something that's strongly discouraged) when you can just read /proc/mounts as a file from either java or native code.

Comment: This seems to be working except I am getting multiple paths read from /proc/mounts that point to the same physical storage and I didn't find way how to identify that these paths refer to the same storage.

Comment: @user1744147 You will have to parse the output according to your needs.